# jQuery Form with Paperclip

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, paperclip, jquery-forms-plugin

I am using [jQuery Form](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) and [Paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) to upload a file from browser to my Rails app.

## Without jQuery form:

```
params = {...
"pic"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f9af9faf0f0
...}
```

## With jQuery form:

```
params = {...
"pic"=>"my_file.png"
...}
```

I am using this code to enable plugin:

```
$('form').ajaxForm(function(){ alert('done'); });
```

## This is my form:

```
<form action="/users" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="user[avatar]">
</form>
```

## Update

jQuery form is sending data with `Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, when  I need 
`Content-Type:multipart/form-data`. I noticed this comparing with jQuery Form official page.

I change my jQuery form code:

```
...
contentType: 'multipart/form-data',
success:function(){ alert('done')
...
```

But content type remains in url encoded.

I am not sure if this is related with multipart/form-data thing. How can I debug this problem?

Comment: What does the form look like? Does it have enctype="multipart/form-data"

Comment: updating... with the form

Comment: Do you have any js errors in the console? Can you show the complete params hash?

Comment: See my updates, I think encoding is my problem, I don't know how to set it correctly.

Comment: Try adding processData: false

Answer (score 1):

From jQuery docs [(source)](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)...

```
processData (default: true)
```

> "By default, data passed in to the data option as an object
>   (technically, anything other than a string) will be processed and
>   transformed into a query string, fitting to the default content-type
>   "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". If you want to send a
>   DOMDocument, or other non-processed data, set this option to false."

So if you set this option to false it should fix your problem.

Comment: It it does not, is weird, because http://malsup.com/jquery/form/progress.html is nothing more than basic call and works.

Comment: Can you post the html/view, you dont have nested forms or something?

Comment: I have jquery_ujs, going to test with that disabled.